# Yii framework how update all records?

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I am using Yii framework.

/view/update.php

```
<?php
    echo CHtml::beginForm();
    foreach ($items as $i=>$item):
        echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$item['name'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$item['c1'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.  count(cos::model()->findAll(array(
            'condition'=>'cos2='.$item['id'],))).'</td>';
    echo '<td>'. CHtml::activeCheckBox($item, "[$i]c2").'</td>';
    echo '<td>'. CHtml::activeCheckBox($item, "[$i]c3").'</td>';
    echo '<td>'. CHtml::activeCheckBox($item, "[$i]c4").'</td>';
    echo '<td>edit</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    endforeach;
    echo '</table>';
    echo CHtml::submitButton('Save');
    echo CHtml::endForm();
?>
```

how can I write all the records at once?

Answer (score 1):

Use updateAll

As an example

```
User::model()->updateAll(array( 'status' => 1, 'updated' => date('Y-m-d' ),
                              'type_id = 1 AND status = 0 '
                      );
```

Comment: Should be `User::model()`

Comment: Well spotted. In future just go ahead and  edit the post as well.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this as reference on how to use the Yii update all

```
CActiveRecord::updateAll($attributes, $condition='', $params=array())
```

http://www.saidur-rahman.com/yii-how-to-updateall-works/

Answer (score 0):

In Yii2, if you are using a Bind Variable (which is recommended) then use the below syntax. In the e.g. Sometable's tr_id and completeby_dt are updated to Null where column tr_id = variable $tr_id.

```
Sometable::updateAll(['tr_id' => NULL, 'completeby_dt' => NULL],
                     'tr_id = :vtrid', [':vtrid' => $tr_id]);
```