# How do I update a row in Yii without using the primary key?

Tags: php, mysql, yii

This is my code:

```
$model= Prices::model()->findByPk($pk);
$model->status = 1;
$model->update(array('status'));
```

This update my row using the primary key, but how do I update a query without the pk in Yii. For instance:

How do I write this query:

```
update mytable set mycolumn = '1' where mycolumn1 ='2' and mycolumn2 = '3' and mycolumn3 = '4' ? Thx
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23712532/yii-framework-how-update-all-records similar to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you tried first string like this?

```
$model= Prices::model()->findByAttributes(
    array(
        'mycolumn1' => 2,
        'mycolumn2' => 3,
        'mycolumn3' => 4
     )
);
$model->mycolumn = 1;
$model->update(array('mycolumn'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way to update your model using [UpdateAll()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#updateAll-detail)

```
Prices::model()->updateAll(
 array('mycolumn'=>1),'mycolumn1=:mycolumn1 AND
 mycolumn2=:mycolumn2 AND mycolumn3=:mycolumn3',
 array(':mycolumn1'=>2,':mycolumn1'=>3,':mycolumn1'=>4)
);
```